# add audio from playing file to microphone stream

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, alsa

I need to add a sound to what the microphone is capturing, is it possible?
I started with

```
man aplay
```

and found that I can do

```
aplay -D PCMdevice filepath.wav
```

so then I listed the PCM devices with

```
~$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=Device
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Device
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Advanced Audio Device, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

But I can't find any PCM device which includes the name mic or capturing or input, everything seems output so I think this is a bad lead.

Has anybody found a way to obtain the result?

Comment: Does your hardware allow this routing? (see `alsamixer`)

Comment: Mhmm I have alsamixer, aplay and arecord working, I didn't know that the hw could allow/deny this operation

Comment: This is not a question of allow/deny, but of whether the hardware has such a connection in the first place.

Comment: I have no idea how to check this, thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you have some "PCM" or "Mix" capture source/volume?

Comment: I added the output of "aplay -L" in case you understand something.

Comment: ... in `alsamixer`?

Comment: in alsamixer I see PCM, PCM Capture Source, Line, Mic, S/PDIF In, Loudness

Comment: And what can you choose as "PCM Capture Source"?

Comment: In "PCM Capture Source" I can choose between "Line", "Mic" and "IEC 958 In"

Comment: An option like using PulseAudio isn't acceptable? http://blog.flipzu.com/2011/02/how-to-mix-voice-and-audio-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: I was hoping to do it entirely with alsa but will give a try, thank you